# Select performance problems in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
        _context.Homestays   
                .Include(x => x.CreatedUser)
                .Include(x => x.UpdatedUser)
                .Include(x => x.HomestayEvaluations)
                .Include(x => x.HomestayContracts)
                .Include(x => x.HomestayPoliceChecks)
                .Include(x => x.HomestayHouseHolds)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Select(x => new Homestay()
                {
                    HomestayId = x.HomestayId,
                    HomestayFamily = ConstValue.GetHomestayFamilyName(x),
                    Address = x.Address,
                    Score = x.HomestayEvaluations.Any(x1 => x1.IsEvaluationActive) ? x.HomestayEvaluations.LastOrDefault(x1 => x1.IsEvaluationActive).GetScore() : 0,
                    Contract = x.HomestayContracts.Any(x1 => x1.IsContractActive) ? x.HomestayContracts.LastOrDefault(x1 => x1.IsContractActive).ContractDate : null,
                    Students = x.Students,
                    HouseHolders = x.HomestayHouseHolds.Count(x1 => x1.IsHouseHoldActive),
                    PoliceCheck = x.HomestayPoliceChecks.Any(x1 => x1.IsPoliceCheckActive) ? x.HomestayPoliceChecks.LastOrDefault(x1 => x1.IsPoliceCheckActive).PoliceCheckDate : null,
                    Language = x.Language,
                    Room = x.Room,
                    IsActive = x.IsActive,
                    CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate,
                    CreatedUserName = ConstValue.GetUserName(x.CreatedUser),
                    UpdatedDate = x.UpdatedDate,
                    UpdatedUserName = ConstValue.GetUserName(x.UpdatedUser)
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.HomestayId);
```

Hello, Im wonder that how do I change my select query better ?

This code as below that it looks messy.
first excute any and if it is true, get last one. but is there any more short code ??

Contract = x.HomestayContracts.Any(x1 => x1.IsContractActive) ? x.HomestayContracts.LastOrDefault(x1 => x1.IsContractActive).ContractDate : null

I tried without any(), it occred error as null object if there is no data.

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Create a stored procedure and execute the stored procedure

Comment: Take a look at [DefaultIfEmpty()](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/02/c.net-little-wonders-empty-defaultifempty-and-count.aspx) `Contract = x.HomestayContracts.Where(x1 => x1.IsContractActive).DefaultIfEmpty().LastOrDefault();`  You can also dump all the .Include() since you reference them in your query.

Comment: Enable "debug" logging, copy SQL from console to SQL Management Studio (or other tool of your choice) and examine this SQL and it's query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Contract = x.HomestayContracts.LastOrDefault(x1 => x1.IsContractActive)?.ContractDate ?? null
```

Also you can disable lazy loading for this query in context's configuration

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

This way you can eliminate Include methods, cause shorter statement but not better performance. Use stored procedure for performance. [Stored Procedure in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Contract = x.HomestayContracts.LastOrDefault(x1 => x1.IsContractActive)?.ContractDate ?? null is not working....... is this for EF core ????????

Comment: No, its c# 6 new feature. It has no difference with your code. Both works same. Mine little shorter.

Comment: VS2013 didn't support C# 6